# Aligning opposite edges of divs

Tags: html, css

I want the green box to lie immediate bottom left to the red header always, even if the user zooms in and out the web page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BvQcx/

Now, I want some margin-left property be given to the green box. Or that the red box is always at the center. Can someone provide me with a jsfiddle solution? The solution must be a div based layout.

Similar Question: [Aligning opposite edges of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841922/aligning-opposite-edges-of-divs)

> ```
>                          |Red Box|
>                |Green Box|
> ```

Comment: Here is a possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/BvQcx/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/XX28t/2/

Need margin left on header, the margin left on the header should equal to the width of the green box

```
margin-left: 20%
```

Comment: There is also a twister attached to it. The width of green box is 100px. Other conditions remain same. No 20% width.

Comment: well if the width is 100px for the green box then make it margin left 100px for the header

Comment: Same problem as mentioned in the above comment by you, if I want the header to always be at the center of the page, then what should be done. Currently, it is more closer to the left of the page.

Comment: oh i see, it is possible but it requires the html structure tobe different. the green box would basically need to be positioned absolutely... I would ask another question about that. It's more complicated

Comment: Could you please post the fiddle or the question at the earliest. Its urgent and thanks for the help.

Comment: Ask another question with the exact requirements

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/XX28t/

```
var sectionSize = $('.leftSection').width();
$('.header').css('marginLeft', sectionSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>set `Float:left` for that `header` too. I hope this will solve your problem.</s>

[<s>Fiddle</s>](http://jsfiddle.net/XX28t/1/)

set position for your header like relative(For supporting Left property. *note:* this is not only the position which supports left and top.). and the then set its left as 20%.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XX28t/5/)

Comment: He wants the header to be centered, not floated left

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<table>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><div style="border: 1px solid red">
    This is the header.
</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><div style="border: 1px solid green">
    This is the header.
</div></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/mQBKx/