# Aligning opposite edges of divs-2

Tags: html, css

I want the green box to lie immediate bottom left to the red header always, even if the user zooms in and out the web page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BvQcx/

Now, I want some margin-left property be given to the green box. Or that the red box is always at the center. Can someone provide me with a jsfiddle solution? The solution must be a div based layout.

Similar Question: [Aligning opposite edges of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841922/aligning-opposite-edges-of-divs)

> ```
>                          |Red Box|
>                |Green Box|
> ```

Comment: Well which one do you want? Left margin added to the green box or the red box always centered. These are two different issues.

Comment: Anything will do. Hence, two issues in one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the green box inside the red box `div`, but make it `position: absolute`. Then shift it left by the width of the green box:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">This is the header.
    <div class="leftSection">This is the left section</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100px;
}
.leftSection {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BvQcx/1/